# Cannot Edit Hangout Chat Api Project Configuration

Tags: google-hangouts

Three days ago, I set up a project for my bot in the Google API Console with the Hangouts Chat API enabled.
In a configuration tab I entered the information for the bot, and everything worked fine. Until now, I cannot edit any information in configuration tab. What happened?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFk08.png)

Answer (score 0):

The bot configuration will be frozen, once you publish the bot. The only workaround is to create a new identical bot with the configuration you wanted.